# How to get out of the while loop in Pygame when after playing the music?

Tags: python, pygame

I have the code down below actually what I want that when one the music get finished it should get out of the while loop automatically. But it isn't getting out of that and if I remove that while loop the song is not getting played.

```py
from pygame import mixer 
    
def mplayer(name): 
    '''  for playing music  '''
    mixer.init() 
    mixer.music.load(name)
    mixer.music.set_volume(0.7) 
    mixer.music.play()

mplayer('welcome.mp3')
while True:
    continue
```

Is there any way that once the music is finished than it should get out the loop?

Comment: and also if there is any better and fast way to play a song in python do let me know

Comment: check out [`pygame.mixer.get_busy`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/mixer.html#pygame.mixer.get_busy)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`mixer.music.get_busy()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/music.html#pygame.mixer.music.get_busy) to test test if any sound is being mixed.

```py
from pygame import mixer

def mplayer(name): 
    '''  for playing music  '''
    mixer.init() 
    mixer.music.load(name)
    mixer.music.set_volume(0.7) 
    mixer.music.play()

mplayer('welcome.mp3')

while mixer.music.get_busy():
    
    # you may have to handle the events here 
    # pygame.event.pump()
    # [...]
    
    pass
```

Note, you may need to handle the events in the loop that is waiting for the music to finish. See [`pygame.event.get()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/event.html#pygame.event.get) respectively [`pygame.event.pump()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/event.html#pygame.event.pump):

> For each frame of your game, you will need to make some sort of call to the event queue. This ensures your program can internally interact with the rest of the operating system.

---

[PyGame](https://www.pygame.org/news) has 2 different modules for playing sound and music, the [pygame.mixer](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/mixer.html) module and the [pygame.mixer.music](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/music.html) module. This module contains classes for loading Sound objects and controlling playback. The difference is explained in the documentation:

> The difference between the music playback and regular Sound playback is that the music is streamed, and never actually loaded all at once. The mixer system only supports a single music stream at once.

If [pygame.mixer.music](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/music.html) doesn't work for you try [pygame.mixer.music](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/music.html):

```py
from pygame import mixer

def mplayer(name): 
    '''  for playing music  '''
    mixer.init()
    my_sound = mixer.Sound(name)
    my_sound.set_volume(0.7) 
    my_sound.play(0)

mplayer('welcome.mp3')

while mixer.get_busy():

    # you may have to handle the events here 
    # pygame.event.pump()
    # [...]
    
    pass
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution of my own problem:↓

```
from pygame import mixer 

def mplayer(name): 
    '''  for playing music  '''
    mixer.init() 
    mixer.music.load(name)
    mixer.music.set_volume(0.7) 
    mixer.music.play()

mplayer('welcome.mp3')

while mixer.music.get_busy():   #just changed this line
    pass
```

Comment: anyway thanks dear for getting me the idea of  .get_busy()

Comment: dude I might be wrong but how can you say that your code is right as it didn't worked for my system.

Comment: So your system behaves different from mine. What works for me doesn't work for you. I just followed the Pygame documentation which clearly says: [`pygame.event.pump()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/event.html#pygame.event.pump):

*"For each frame of your game, you will need to make some sort of call to the event queue. This ensures your program can internally interact with the rest of the operating system."*